# I need help passing an array of structs to a function

Tags: c, arrays, struct

I have been working on this for days now and cannot figure out what I'm doing wrong. i have a struct...

```
typedef struct{

   int usedFlag;
   char *course; /*size: NAME*/
   int courseID;
   int numberOfStudents;
   int *studentID; /*size: MAXSTDINCLS*/
   grades *assignments; /*size: MAXGRDS*/
}course;

typedef  struct
{

   char *assignment;/*size: NAME*/
   int *grades; /*size: MAXSTDINCLS*/
}grades;
```

this is how i allocated memory...

```
course *allClasses;
allClasses = (course*)malloc(sizeof(course)*CLSSIZE);

for (counter= 0; counter < CLSSIZE; counter++)
{
    allClasses[counter].course = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*NAME);
    allClasses[counter].studentID = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*MAXSTDINCLS);
    allClasses[counter].assignments = (grades*)malloc(sizeof(grades)*MAXGRDS);
    /*memory allocation for all of grades arrays, using "courses" array of "grades"*/
    for(secondCounter = 0; secondCounter < MAXGRDS; secondCounter++)
    {
        allClasses[counter].assignments[secondCounter].assignment = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*NAME);
        allClasses[counter].assignments[secondCounter].grades = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*MAXSTDINCLS);
    }
}
```

so none of this has given me trouble, however, i need to pass this array into a function, and in the function i will either take in information or reallocate memory to make the array bigger, and this is where i get problems.

```
void addNewCourse(course *allClasses[])
{
    printf("%d", (*allClasses[0]).courseID);
    printf("%d", (*allClasses[1]).courseID);
}
```

this is my function, and I've simplified it as much as possible, in my last few days I've managed to discover that I'm able to print out the first element in the array, but i can't print out any others, in main, i pass my function like this...

```
addNewCourse(&allClasses);
```

i seriously don't know what to try anymore, I've tried everything, I've read every answer possible and can't find a solution to my problem, please help

Comment: Could you try `(*(allClasses)[0]).courseID);` ?

Comment: yeah, I've tried that, i've even tried allClasses[1]->courseID, which is the same thing

Comment: It is not the same thing ! `allClasses[1]->courseID` means that `allClasses` is an array of pointer to struct, while `(*(allClasses)[1]).courseID` means that `allClasses` is a pointer to an array of structs.

Comment: It is not clear from the q how you put info into the array, nor how you reallocate memory to make the array bigger. What specific problem do you see? Segfault? Where specifically does it occur?

Comment: oh, thank you, i didm;t know that! but it still didn't work :(

Comment: Then, the problem may be elsewhere...Could you try to flush stdout by doing something like `printf("%d", (*(allClasses)[1]).courseID);fflush(stdout);`

Comment: THANK YOU ALL!! the problem was the pointer precedence, i have no i idea there was a difference between allClasses[1]->courseID and (*(allClasses)[1]).courseID and thank you francis

Comment: @TheCoolestTaco: I rolled your question back to the revision before you deleted almost everything and changed all of the tags, especially the language one, so that what was left made no sense. If you did this intentionally, you need to know that self-vandalism (editing questions in such a way as to make them useless to others) is a violation of site rules. See [_Anything that should be done about a user “gutting” questions?_](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/275864/anything-that-should-be-done-about-a-user-gutting-questions/275866#275866)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Array subscript has higher precedence over dereference operator.

`*allClasses[1]` is then `*(allClasses[1])`, you need `(*allClasses)[0]`.

Also remember arrays decay as pointers to the first elmenent when passed to functions, and so it's better to avoid syntax like `course *allClasses[]`.

Call

```
addNewCourse(&allClasses);
```

Then,

```
void addNewCourse(course **allClasse)
{
    printf("%d", (*allClasses)[0].courseID);
    printf("%d", (*allClasses)[1].courseID);
}
```

Comment: how can i pass the array as a reference then if i want to reallocate more memory? if i don't pass it be reference then once it gets back to main it will be the same size won't it?

Comment: @TheCoolestTaco If you need to to reallocate memory, you will need a double pointer, I have edited my answer

Answer (score 2):

`allClasses` is an array of `course`s and you are expecting an array of pointer to `course`:

```
void addNewCourse(course *allClasses[])
```

Change to

```
void addNewCourse(course *allClasses)
```

> yeah i did it that way intentionally because i want to allocate memory

If you want to allocate memory for n `course`s through a function:

```
void addNewCourse(course **allClasses, int n)
{
    *allClasses = malloc(sizeof(course) * n);
    /* ... */
}

course *allClasses;
addNewCourse(&allClasses, CLSSIZE);
```

or

```
course *addNewCourse(int n)
{
    course *allClasses = malloc(sizeof(course) * n);
    /* ... */
    return allClasses;
}

course *allClasses;
allClasses = addNewCourse(CLSSIZE);
```

Comment: yeah i did it that way intentionally because i want to allocate memory, so i passed the array of course by reference, so its a double pointer

Comment: This answer is correct, you don't need a double pointer for what you are trying to do unless the function `addNewCourse` is going to resize the array.

Comment: If it seems more clear, you could make the signature be `void addNewCourse(course allClasses[]);`

Comment: it is, the function addNewCourse does resize the array, which is why i'm confused. Don't i need to pass the array as a reference? cause if i don't, once i get back to main won't it be the same size?

Answer (score 0):

```
void addNewCourse(course *allClasses)
{
    printf("%d", allClasses[0].courseID);
    printf("%d", allClasses[1].courseID);
}
```

This should work. Because allClasses is a pointer of course.

Answer (score 0):

divide and conquer 
break it up, into a function that allocates memory, like

```
course* allocateCourseArray( int );
```

and others that fills in values / read values etc

```
void writeToCourseArray( course*, int );
void printCourseArray( course*, int );
```

use them like:

```
const int SZ = 5;
course* myArr = allocateCourseArray(SZ);
writeToCourseArray(myArr,SZ);
printCourseArray(myArr,SZ);
```

inside `writeToCourseArray` you access individual elements with 
`arrayname[indexnumber].membername` syntax

If the array need to change size dynamically, you also need a

```
course* resizeCourseArray( course*, int );
```

`realloc` makes that easy to implement. Use like:

```
myArr = resizeCourseArray( myArr, newsize );
```

note that traditionally user-defined types are capitalized, like `Course`

Answer (score 0):

You don't show that in your example, but it appears that you want to allocate memory for new courses, so you must pass the address of your `courses` array as pointer to pointer and access it via `(*arr)[i]`.

You will also need a means to pass the length of the array and update it. This can be an extra variable or mabe a sentinel entry at the end of the array.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct Course Course;

struct Course {
    int id;
    const char *name;
};

void add_course(Course **courses, int *n, int id, const char *name)
{
    *courses = realloc(*courses, (*n + 1) * sizeof(**courses));

    (*courses)[*n].id = id;
    (*courses)[*n].name = name; 
    (*n)++;
}

int main()
{
    Course *courses = NULL;    
    int i, n;

    add_course(&courses, &n, 1101, "Biology (Basic)");
    add_course(&courses, &n, 1102, "Biology (Intermediate)");
    add_course(&courses, &n, 1103, "Biology (Expert)");

    add_course(&courses, &n, 2101, "Pig Latin");

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("%8d   %s\n", courses[i].id, courses[i].name);
    }

    free(courses);

    return 0;
}
```

This solution works, but you have to take care that the actual number of elements and the counter `n` are always synchronised. It might be a good idea to bundle them into a separate struct. You pass pointers to this control struct to functions and can do away with the pointer-to-pointer syntax and the ambiguity between `*a[i]` and (*a)[i]`.

Here's the ame example with a control struct:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct Curriculum Curriculum;
typedef struct Course Course;

struct Course {
    int id;
    const char *name;
};

struct Curriculum {
    Course *courses;
    size_t n;
};

void add_course(Curriculum *curr, int id, const char *name)
{
    int n = curr->n++;

    curr->courses = realloc(curr->courses,
        curr->n * sizeof(*curr->courses));

    curr->courses[n].id = id;
    curr->courses[n].name = name; 
}

void print_courses(const Curriculum *curr)
{
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < curr->n; i++) {
        printf("%8d   %s\n",
            curr->courses[i].id, 
            curr->courses[i].name);
    }
}

int main()
{
    Curriculum curr = {NULL};

    add_course(&curr, 1101, "Biology (Basic)");
    add_course(&curr, 1102, "Biology (Intermediate)");
    add_course(&curr, 1103, "Biology (Expert)");

    add_course(&curr, 2101, "Pig Latin");

    print_courses(&curr);    
    free(curr.courses);

    return 0;
}
```